# Objects and Players falling through static ground

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I just started to learn how to use spritebuilder since basically everyone told me it saves a lot of time and easy to integrate things, but I am running to an issue where the objects and players that are suppose to sit on the ground fall through.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a single CCPhysicsNode that contains *all* the physics objects of your game.

Your setup effectively creates two separate physics worlds that won't interact with each other, therefore rock and guy will never be able to "make contact" with ground.

Interestingly you tagged this with [sprite-kit](/questions/tagged/sprite-kit) so if you are using the (not officially released, no longer in development) SpriteBuilder version that supports Sprite Kit, know that CCPhysicsNode will not function at all. The SpriteBuilder Sprite Kit version does not support physics.